# Python string assignment error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have been practising Python and 2D list assignment. I have been trying to create a calendar with 7 days each having 24 hours (empty strings) for each day.

```
day = [""] * 24
timetable = day * 7

    timetable[0][15] = "meeting with Jane"
```

But when I try to assign the above string I get the Typeerror.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\workspace\test\2D.py", line 7, in <module>
timetable[0][15] = "meeting with Jane"
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I understand strings are immutable and cannot be reassigned values so I used `.append()` method of the list but still it didn't work.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how can i assign a string here? I am getting an error as shown above.

Answer (score 6):

```
timetable = day * 7
```

This does not make a 2-dimensional list; it makes a 1-dimensional list that is 7 times as long as `day` is.

Try this instead:

```
timetable = [day[:] for _ in range(7)]
```

This makes `timetable` be a list which is 7 copies of `day`. The copy bit (`[:]`, a full slice) is necessary to avoid the different days all referring to the same list, which would mean that if you modified one day all of the days would change - probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks and how do i assign a string to someday.
Example: If I want to assign a string to Tuesday at 13 hours then how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

After doing:

```
timetable = [day[:] for _ in range(7)]
```

as [Amber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2457969/skyrocker) said, you can do the string assignment as you previously tried:

```
timetable[0][15] = "meeting with Jane"
```

Now the first day has has the 16th hour assigned as 'meeting with Jane'.